# Extra folders in outlook client

Tags: office365, exchange-server

After migrating users from on-prem exchange to o365 exchange, when I set up local outlook clients there are a number of extra folders that appear in the outlook client.  Does anyone know why this occurs and is there anything that can be done to remove them? Thank you for any assistance.

[image]

Comment: Are you using different languages for the source and target?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by languages.  Like programming languages, or actual languages?

Comment: The language from the mailbox, I have seen such an similar issue when the user initial had a France mailbox configured but later one got an English one. The dublicated folders appear.

Comment: All the mailboxes were and still are English from Canada.  No change in Language.  My lead tech used a Microsoft tool to migrate them, but it only migrates the mailbox.  It doesn't do the calendar or contacts.  I think the tool was called IMAP or something like that.